# Read Pdf file and convert to html elements

Tags: c#, jquery, html, pdf, model-view-controller

We have requirement to read pdf file and need to convert it as html elements( i,e. text, date field, textarea etc). is there any plugin available...or any other method.

Comment: Did you try to find something similar? To understand what you need.

Comment: This might get closed as opinion based since it's basically asking for a tool. Just a heads up.

Comment: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Information can help you

**nuget**

```
PM> Install-Package sautinsoft.pdffocus
```

**example**

```
string pathToPdf = @"d:\Tempos\table.pdf"; 
string pathToHtml = Path.ChangeExtension(pathToPdf, ".htm"); 

// Convert PDF file to HTML file 
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus(); 
// You may download the latest version of SDK here:  
// www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/download.php  

 
// Let's force the component to store images inside HTML document 
// using base-64 encoding 
f.HtmlOptions.IncludeImageInHtml = true; 
f.HtmlOptions.Title = "Simple text"; 

// This property is necessary only for registered version 
 

f.OpenPdf(pathToPdf); 

if (f.PageCount > 0) 
{ 
    int result = f.ToHtml(pathToHtml); 

    //Show HTML document in browser 
    if (result == 0) 
    { 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToHtml); 
    } 
}
```